# for array loop use int or uint8_t?

Tags: c

If I am looping through an array, should I use `int` or `uint8_t`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {}
```

or

```
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) {}
```

Which is better when working with embedded systems?

Comment: Usually `int` will be the natural register size and hence fastest.  The smaller integer types are mostly useful for structs and arrays where you want to minimize the space required.

Comment: `int_fast8_t` is the optimal solution

Comment: @M.M: why not `uint_fast8_t` ?

Comment: @chqrlie signed arithmetic has fewer constraints that unsigned arithmetic, so in theory, all other things being equal, the signed version should be equal or faster in performance to the unsigned

Comment: Unsigned integer is actually a good source of subtle bugs in production software, and rarely offers anything meaningful. It is sometime suggested to use unsigned integer only in bit pattern representation.

Comment: @WiSaGaN: I agree with you, but if the boundary is an unsigned type, using a signed index is calling for trouble.

Comment: @M.M: signed arithmetic is more intuitive for the programmer, but I have yet to see a CPU where signed arithmetic offers any performance advantage over unsigned arithmetic, it is actually quite the contrary: `i / 2` can be optimized into `i >> 1` if `i` is unsigned or known to be positive, not in the general signed case.

Comment: if negative values were possible then unsigned could not be used anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first choice is much better:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { }
```

The alternative is sometimes encouraged by local coding rules, it is a bad recommendation:

- it tends to generate more code if you use `i` in the loop body as an index or in an expression.
- it can also lead to more bugs especially if you later modify your code and the upper boundary exceeds 255 and is read from a `unsigned` variable.
- a good embedded compiler will take advantage of the small range if it is pertinent anyway.

Embedded systems have plenty of resources nowadays, but if you are targeting a very limited chipset, you may want to check both alternatives and make an informed decision.

Answer (score 1):

Use `int`. Just use `int`. That's what it's for. If you had to think about and pick the size in bits for every variable, that'd be a nuisance, that'd indicate you were using a poor language, that wasn't doing its job.  It would be as bad as if you had to pick the machine instructions to evaluate every expression you wrote. But C is a good language. Let it generate your code efficiently. Let it worry about the exact sizes of variables when you don't care, which ought to be most of the time. Just use `int`.

Comment: note: this advice only holds so long as the loop upper bound doesn't reach 32767 :)

Answer (score 0):

depends on the chip you are targeting

on an 8bit chip, it could make a difference using an 8bit type, however even on an 8 bit chip they often have one register that is of a bigger size.

In some cases it might help with stack usage.

In general I suggest using a unsigned for a loop anyways, but it's up to you to make informed choices on the bit width you need.

Comment: I would actually suggest signed integers for loop, so you don't have to switch between signed/unsigned when loop direction is reversed.

Comment: @WiSaGaN: You do not need to switch if you use this style: `for (unsigned i = 100; i-- > 0; ) { }`

Comment: @chqrlie, I think usually in computer industry we want 99..0 inclusive, rather than 100..1 inclusive.

Comment: @WiSaGaN: read more carefully, the loop style I use enumerates 99..0 inclusively **and** uses the exact count as initializer. Best of both worlds.

Comment: @chqrlie OK. My bad on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pointer to array type and use post increment per loop. Then define magic number as constant plus max offset for sizeof() to array limit. Store address once per instantiating.

If you are over thinking it then you may as well go to assembly.

Or you can apply the unix philosophy and get it working.  Optimization is another step.